# How to work with two networks is one script?

Tags: python-3.x, backend, ethernet, wifi

I work in company where there are strict restrictions on the network. I need to write an application in python 3, where a wired connection and wi-fi will be used simultaneously. For example, to send data to internal resources, I will use Ethernet and to go data from the network use wi-fi

Comment: What have you tried? Why do you think this should be a problem? I assume the internal network has a different IP range?

Comment: So it can be solved by sudo route?

Comment: Your question does not have enough information to answer that. But the output of `sudo route -n` might help to understand what your problem is, in combination with the IP address of the "internal resource". Have you even tried just accessing it? If it didn't work, what was the error message? You need to provide some information.